# How to append the node position number as an element to XML using XSLT?

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xslt

I have the following XML which needs to be transformed as given in  the ‘expected output’ section given below.

The requirements for transformation are:

1. Sibling nodes such as dependents and locations need to be appended with their corresponding position ids .. for example.. if multiple dependents nodes are exist in the file, nodes should be displayed as ,  etc..
2. Position of sibling nodes needs to be inserted as separate element names under their corresponding child nodes

**Sample XML input file**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<workers>
 <worker>
  <name>sam</name>
  <batch_id>1345</batch_id>
  <dependents>
   <name>sara</name>
  </dependents>
  <dependents>
   <name>tom</name>
  </dependents>
  <dependents>
   <name>harry</name>
  </dependents>
  <locations>
   <place>ny</place>
   <type>work</type>
  </locations>
  <locations>
   <place>sfo</place>
   <type>home</type>
  </locations>
 </worker>
</workers>
```

**Expected Output**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<workers>
 <worker>
  <name>sam</name>
  <batch_id>1345</batch_id>
  <dependents1>
   <name>sara</name>
  </dependents1>
  <dependents_row1>1</dependents_row1>
  <dependents2>
   <name>tom</name>
  </dependents2>
  <dependents_row2>2</dependents_row2>
  <dependents3>
   <name>harry</name>
  </dependents3>
  <dependents_row3>3</dependents_row3>
  <locations1>
   <place>ny</place>
   <type>work</type>
  </locations1>
  <locations_row1>1</locations_row1>
  <locations2>
   <place>sfo</place>
   <type>home</type>
  </locations2>
  <locations_row2>2</locations_row2>
 </worker>
</workers>
```

Comment: Whose idea is that target design? It will be difficult to process that with most XML APIs in an elegant and efficient way if you have element names with an index appended as neither DOM (e.g. `getElementsByTagName`) nor XSLT/XPath/XQuery (e.g. `child::foo`) have any direct way to express a variable element name (in XSLT/XPath/XQuery you can use `child::*[starts-with(local-name(), 'foo')]` but that is rather cumbersome). So why do you think you need that target design?

Comment: As for creating that with XSLT, use `<xsl:number/>` with a variable to generate the index and `<xsl:element name="{name()}{$variable}">` to generate the element. Identifying whether an element has siblings is bit more work but using a key also allows, you might need to tell us whether you can work with XSLT 2 or 3 or a stuck with XSLT 1.

Comment: This is a requirement of a downstream system. They wanted to get an xml file with unique element names. In my case, i need to make only a couple of sibling nodes unique, so it's not necessary to check whether an element has a sibling or not(I have used those words just to represent my example better). I can even write a template match condition to specify the sibling nodes that needs to be made unique.

Comment: I can work with xslt 2.0, thanks Martin for your quick response. Would you be able to share me the code that does this trick? I'm just beginner in XML/XSLT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following stylesheet (despite of the given design doubts):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <!-- identity template -->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/workers/worker">           <!-- handles the sub-elements of the worker node -->
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::dependents or self::locations)]" />   
            <xsl:apply-templates select="dependents" />   
            <xsl:apply-templates select="locations" />   
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="dependents|locations">      <!-- handles the addition of the position nodes -->
        <xsl:element name="{concat(local-name(),position())}">
            <xsl:copy-of select="*" />
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="{concat(local-name(),'_row',position())}">
            <xsl:value-of select="position()" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you zx485, I see that code is version 1.0 ... Is there a different way to do this in version 2.0 ?

Comment: @Anoop: I just updated my answer. It works both with XSLT-1.0 and 2.0 or above.

Comment: Thank you zx485, l'm testing this.

Answer (score 1):

A generic solution that doesn't know about the element names and that uses `xsl:number` as suggested in a comment is

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs">

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[some $sibling in (preceding-sibling::*, following-sibling::*) satisfies node-name($sibling) = node-name(.)]">
      <xsl:variable name="index" as="xs:integer">
          <xsl:number/>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:element name="{name()}{$index}">
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:element>
      <xsl:element name="{name()}_row{$index}">
          <xsl:value-of select="$index"/>
      </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

Of course you can reduce or simplify the `match="*[some $sibling in (preceding-sibling::*, following-sibling::*) satisfies node-name($sibling) = node-name(.)]"` to e.g. `match="descendents | locations"` if the elements are known and/or only certain ones are targetted.

http://xsltransform.hikmatu.com/6qM2e2o/2

Comment: Thank you Martin, I'm checking this too.